# draw images on xaxis in GWT highcharts

Tags: gwt, highcharts

I am trying to create image on every xaxis in my highchart like the one in the attached image , but couldn't find the way for it

here is my code for the xaxis

```
         chart.getXAxis(1).setOpposite(true).setLinkedTo(0).setType(Type.DATE_TIME)
    .setTickInterval(6 * 3600 *1000).setGridLineWidth(1)
```

any idea how can i set some image to every xaxis in my chart

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You will want to use the [AxisLabelsFormatter](http://www.moxiegroup.com/moxieapps/gwt-highcharts/apidocs/org/moxieapps/gwt/highcharts/client/labels/AxisLabelsFormatter.html).  The content you "return" from this call should be the appropriate html you want to have rendered.  So something like this work for the top axis:

```
chart.getXAxis().setLabels(
   new XAxisLabels()
     .setFormatter(new AxisLabelsFormatter() {
        public String format(AxisLabelsData axisLabelsData) {
            return '<img src="/path/to/image.gif" />';
        }
     })
 );
```